# Is there a way to have images on a Google Slide update based on a criteria or spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-slides

I have a Google Slide which I use as an information display. Using linked objects, it gets its information from a Google Sheet (which in turn gets the relevant information from my input using a series of lookups).

I had hoped to embed images into my Google Sheet and have the images come over via the linked objects, however the linked objects do not carry over images embedded in the cells.

I'm looking for a solution to update the images in the Slides via information in Sheets. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*If the images are embedded in the cells of a Sheet, it is not possible to obtain these in any form from the Google Sheets API nor from Google Apps Script.*

#### More Information:

Inserting images into cells was only implemented as a feature in Google sheets in 2019 and so as of the writing of this answer, there isn't a way of copying these out of the cells using Apps Script or the API as an endpoint for it is yet to exist.

You can see this by making a `get`<sup>[[1]](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)</sup> request of a cell and read all the raw data it returns:

**Request:**

```txt
spreadsheetId: "ID of private Spreadsheet created in Drive"
includeGridData: True
ranges: D7
fields: sheets/data/rowData/values
```

**Response:**

````json
```{
  "sheets": [
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "rowData": [
            {
              "values": [
                {
                  "userEnteredValue": {},
                  "effectiveValue": {},
                  "effectiveFormat": {
                    "backgroundColor": {
                      "red": 1,
                      "green": 1,
                      "blue": 1
                    },
                    "padding": {
                      "top": 2,
                      "right": 3,
                      "bottom": 2,
                      "left": 3
                    },
                    "horizontalAlignment": "LEFT",
                    "verticalAlignment": "BOTTOM",
                    "wrapStrategy": "OVERFLOW_CELL",
                    "textFormat": {
                      "foregroundColor": {},
                      "fontFamily": "Arial",
                      "fontSize": 10,
                      "bold": false,
                      "italic": false,
                      "strikethrough": false,
                      "underline": false
                    },
                    "hyperlinkDisplayType": "PLAIN_TEXT"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
````

As you can see, no image data is returned for the cell in question.

#### Feature Request:

There is however a Feature request on Google’s Issue Tracker for being able to insert and obtain images in cells via the API<sup>[[2]](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129384672)</sup>. You can head over to the Feature Request page and click the `☆` in the top left, which lets Google know that you also would like this feature, and will automatically get updates about its progress.

#### References:

1. [Google Sheets > API v4 - Method `spreadsheets.get`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)
2. [Google Issue Tracker - Insert images in cell](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129384672)